# MySQL - Querying the name of the month

Tags: php, mysql, dql

I wrote a query in my Symfony that returns total sum of amounts per month of a year. But when I try to convert it from month number to month name it trows

> Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ","

My code..

```
$resultYearly = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
       ->select('MONTH(p.transactionDate, \'%b\') AS MonthOfYear, sum(p.amount) Total')
MonthAndYear, sum(p.amount) Total')
            ->where('p.transactionDate >= :end')
            ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime('-1 year'))
            ->groupBy( 'MonthOfYear')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

It works perfect with  DATE_FORMAT but when I use MONTH it throws an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
DATE_FORMAT(p.transactionDate,'%b')  AS MonthOfYear
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the part of `\'%b\'` from the `Month` function, since `MONTH` function takes only one parameter, which is date.
So your code should be:

```
$resultYearly = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
       ->select('MONTH(p.transactionDate) AS MonthOfYear, sum(p.amount) Total')
MonthAndYear, sum(p.amount) Total')
            ->where('p.transactionDate >= :end')
            ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime('-1 year'))
            ->groupBy( 'MonthOfYear')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I want for my results to be converted in month NAMES not in month NUMBERS.. @RayA

Comment: the you may consider using DATE_FORMAT